# firebase Auth / login Vulnerabilities?

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

**Context:** I just got an email which I believe is spam from `admin@typingchimp.com` saying my auth users accounts can be stolen and asked if there are security bounties. I use firebase auth, and it should be easy to see that checking client side JS code. Although I think it's spam, it leads me to ask:

**Are there any known security vulnerabilities or ideal security related settings for firebase auth? Perhaps an article or documentation beyond https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics or https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth ?**

PS: *This is an auth-only question*, but yes my Real-time DB restricts read access to the signed in user and doesn't allow write access. No other settings have been changed beyond this. My site uses SSL of course.

I know google limits individual IPs from making a bunch of failed login attempts and will block you temporarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I regularly get these types of emails (spam!) indicating that they have already found security flaws, or that they will, for a "finders fee".  It is a marketing campaign trying to drum up sales activity.

Firebase Authentication has been designed and is in use by millions of apps.  Hundreds of millions (or billions??) of accounts live in Firebase Auth.  If there are vulnerabilities with the service, we will learn of it rapidly.

There is the potential that your particular use of Firebase Auth does not follow secure practices.  For example, if you have your API keys checked into a publicly available code repository.

However if you follow the (fairly straightforward) "getting started" and recommendations docs from the Firebase team, odds are that your app is just fine.

Comment: Thank you @GregFenton I agree with your analysis, I'm glad to hear there are tons of these "finders fee" emails going out.